# google analytics to track goal conversions - re directs

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, data-conversion

I am using google analytics to track goal conversions, using a bridge page which then re directs the user to the affiliate website.

I have a question regarding the time out before it re directs. What's the quickest time you can set your page to redirect so Google can collect the analytics goal conversions data?

Below is the code I use on my bridge page before it redirects, it's set to: 1500 - 1 and a half seconds delay.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location = "http://www.example.com"; },1500);
</script>
```

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Many Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

You can use [analytics events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) to make sure the redirect was recorded before it's redirected.

```
//Fires after page load
addListener(document, 'load', function() {
//Sends an event for page which where the action was redirect and the value is the current page
  ga('send', 'event', 'page', 'redirect', document.location);
//Refferes to new location after recording the action.
  window.location = NEW_LOCATION
});
```

Comment: Hi Raam86, thanks for your reply. I'm using  setTimeout(function(){ window.location = "http://www.example.com"; },1500); I'm interested to know how fast Google can pick up the goal conversions code, what time limit? I think I could make the page re direct faster, but not sure?

Comment: This will always redirect immediately